# deploying ElasticSearch production using multiple clusters and nodes under docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am new to launching ES for the production environment. I want to create production-ready ElasticSearch clusters having master nodes and data and backup nodes and etc. I read tutorials on the internet regarding this matter including the [official document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-docker.html) but I cannot get my head around the topic in the official document it's running multiple clusters under one machine what if that machine goes down for some reason? where are the master nodes playing in that scenario? where are the backup nodes? to protect against data loss?

I want to know if there are any straightforward solutions that I can use for deploying the ES on multiple machines serving the same purpose (for one project with specific data types) that can be easily distributed and fault-tolerant?

Comment: what is your servers configuration? are you using cloud platform or bare metal? why do want to use docker? how much record do you have? (daily and monthly)

Comment: this documentation is for someone who have very strong server (at least 32 TB disk and 256 GB ram) and insist to have multiple instance to avoid more than 32 GB heap. or for lab environment.

Comment: @hamidbayat it's cloud / deployment with docker isn't a *must* I can deploy without it / the expectation for records is a few million records per day which of course they are going to get processed afterward.

Comment: if you have low resources in each server, run one instance with docker on each server .

Comment: @hamidbayat The question is, how can create a distributed ES nodes connected with 
each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple containers on a single host makes sense if you have a lot of resources on a given host that you want to partition up and use efficiently. then you can have multiple hosts with multiple Elasticsearch containers forming a cluster

If you do that, look at using [allocation awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.14/modules-cluster.html#shard-allocation-awareness) to make sure shards are adequately balanced so that the loss of a single host will mean you maintain your data